# Search Duplicate Cells in Column and Incrementally Append Number to create Unique Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that has duplicate entries. I need to create unique values for each entry by adding a number to the end of it.

Example:
Column A

1. John Doe
2. Jack Tee
3. John Doe

Column B (solution Column)

1. John Doe
2. Jack Tee
3. John Doe 1

I searched a lot and couldn't find an answer! Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Microsoft (excel) 365 and running the latest version, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Countif can do that for you:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,A2 & " " & COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)-1, A2)
```

[image]

Comment: You are the BEST! thank you! I spent hours trying to figure this out..

Comment: @Sim you should `accept` this answer before seeking more free help as your followup item was not part of your question.

Comment: @pgSystemTester thanks. I am new to posting questions, I wasn't sure the way to go about it.. I accepted the answer.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad do you know if there a way to make it that if there is a duplicate, then already start counting 1 from the first entry? But if there isn't a duplicate then leave it as is. IE: John Doe 1 , Jack Tee , John Doe 2

Comment: `=CHOOSE(MIN(2, COUNTIF(A:A,A2)),A2,A2 & " " & COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2))`